# How do I unlock the Battlefield 3 soldier in multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3-multiplayer, mass-effect-3

My friend has a fifth option available for his soldier class in multiplayer called "Battlefield 3". It looks similar to the human male model, but features the characteristic [glowworm look](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/58/Bf3-pc-cover.jpg) as well as the Carnage ability in place of Concussive Shot.

**How do I unlock the "glowworm soldier"?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to own Battlefield Three on Origin. For the consoles, at least, you only need a save file.

See [here](http://www.justpushstart.com/2012/03/mass-effect-3-gives-battlefield-3-owners-an-exclusive-kit-for-co-op/).

[image]

From what I've been hearing, the Battlefield 3 Soldier comes from the Starter Pack for those eligible. I'm not sure if there's a way to unlock him if you acquire Battlefield 3 *after* starting the Mass Effect 3 multiplayer.